# selenium driver not saving the webpage content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Below code is creating an empty task_list.html file. It is not saving the full html content file , which is what i want . How to fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
html = driver.page_source
driver.get("<our_internal_work_website>")
with open(r"C:\Users\task_list.html", "wb") as f:
 f.write(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

Few points:

1. I am brand new to Python, just started few days back and troubleshooting issues as they come by searching on stackoverflow.
2. I am running this code on interactive shell on Powershell in Windows 10.
3. I manually enter the login credentials when  opens . I have still not reached expertise to be able to put login details automatically.
4. I do not have html/css knowledge ,  so will google around in order to troubleshoot.
5. I want to use beautiful soup in order to parse the html , but it also requires login credentials and i do not know where to put the login credentials because it doesnt explicitly open the "Firefox" browser. Due to that , for now i am working with Selenium, because it can open the Firefox browser.

Comment: Note that you're trying to get page source **before** navigating to target page, so simply put `html = driver.page_source` after `driver.get("<our_internal_work_website>")`. Also note that there is no need to use Selenium to get page source. Consider to use `python-requests`, `pycURL`, `urllib`, etc...

Comment: Can i use python-requests, pycURL,urllib for opening the Firefox web browser and explicitly passing the login credentials also? Sorry if i am not supposed to be asking a slightly different question also :)

Comment: No. You cannot open browser with that tools, but you can pass credentials to your HTTP requests, e.g. `requests.get("<our_internal_work_website>", auth=("<yout_username>", "<your_password>"))`

Comment: will try . Problem is after the login, i will to click "I agree" one pop before it redirects me to the actual webpage i want to download :(  . how to get past that

Comment: You should check the request that your browser sends when you do that. To check it: press F12 -> switch to Network tab -> Click "I agree" -> check new request

Comment: tried requests.get . it didnt work , still getting  raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Authorization Required for url

Comment: There are several authentication types. You need to choose [proper approach](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)